# Invariant Violation in react native when using Checkbox from Material UI

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use Checkbox from material-ui , but I don't know why I am getting Invariant error message

Error:

```
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `path` must be a function (received `undefined`). 
Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.
```

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,} from 'react-native';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { tick: false };
    this.checkTick = this.checkTick.bind(this);
  }
  checkTick() {
    this.setState({ tick: !this.state.tick });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
          <View>
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.state.tick}
              onPress={this.checkTick}
              color="primary"
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
};
```

If I use CheckBox from `react-native-elements`, then I am not getting this error.
But I want to use Checkbox from material UI

Answer (score 0):

The `material-ui` package is for ReactJS web and not for React Native. You can't use this package with React Native.

Comment: can you suggest me the alternative for material-ui for react native

Comment: Check out [React Native Paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/). It is a UI package which is based on Google's material design guidelines.